# When I drag and drop my user control onto the design surface, it is showing up as a LINK?

Tags: user-controls

Has anyone seen this.  Ive done this before and its not been a problem, but now I am trying to drag and drop and it keep showing the files location in a link... ?

Comment: What platform? This could be just about anything.

Comment: What language/framework is this?

Comment: Excuse me, but what are you talking about? What language? What IDE?

You can't make a post like that... how are we supposed to know what you're talkin about?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, I have seen this happen when you drag a UserControl onto the Source view of an ASP.Net .aspx page. Be sure you are dragging the UserControl onto the Design surface.

Edit: [This fellow](http://forums.asp.net/p/1199572/2083734.aspx) was able to solve his problem by reinstalling Visual Studio. Not a happy thought, but if you're using a recently-installed version, it might be worth a try.

Comment: thanks but I am dropping right onto the design surface -- its driving me batty...